# Can I copy an artboard with link in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, copy-and-paste

I am trying to create a card, and wish to duplicate it multiple times on a page, while keeping the copies in sync with the source artboard.  The idea is like copy with link in Word or Excel.

Is this possible in Illustrator?  Or, is there a workaround?

I looked at Symbol, but it seems to be useful only for simple objects, not the whole artboard.  However, my artboard is fairly simple, just a bunch of texts.

If this can be done somehow, I will then import variables to create a total of 6000 some cards.  But, this is a separate issue, just a consideration for solving the current issue.

Comment: Do it in two steps. First batch the data into the cards then distribute. (most likely you dont need to distribute since the printer can merge the individual cards on papers)

Comment: Are you saying that I only need to create the individual cards and then output the PDF files, containing one card each.  Then, the printer would be able to print 10 copies each on a page?

Comment: All our digital presses and inkjets have a control software that enable this easily. Hell even my home printer can do this ()but it does have a PS interpretter . And then the placing trick below works, you dont actually have to place the 6000 PDF files just make one template then have a JavaScript update the links for every sheet.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I got it.  I'll take some more online lessons and try it and see where it takes me

Answer (score 1):

You **can** use `File > Place` to place one .ai file into another .ai file as a link.

Editing the original file would then cause all links to it to ask to be updated.

Comment: Yes, it works for a single card, thank you!  However, I have more than 6000 cards, which means I will have to generate 6000 cards using variable, and then create 6000 AI files and manually linking each such file to a separate card file.  This is going to be tedious and error-prone.  Perhaps I can write a script to do this?  But I will eventually end up with over 6000 PDF files for the printer.  Am I missing something here?